# WinForms setup DataGridView with one column bound to List

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C# 4.0 and WinForms. I'm trying to get my DataGridView to be setup like this

```
[CheckBox]  [TextColumn]  [ComboBoxColumn]
```

This is for a menu similar to the SQL Server Import/Export tool. The checkbox will tell me whether the table is to be transferred. TextColumn is the source table name. And ComboBoxColumn is a list of the tables in the destination database.

Example

```
[Transfer]  [SourceTable]  [DestinationTable]
    X       MyTableSource  MyTableDest
```

Where MyTableDest would be a list I could choose from like (TableA, TableB, TableC), or I could input my own name.

I tried this.dataGridView.DataSource = myBindingList where mybindingList has my custom object that looks like

```
public class Mine {
   public bool Transfer { get; set;}
   public string Source { get; set;}
   public List<string> Destination { get; set; }
}
```

I don't need a full solution - just direction on how to achieve this

Comment: Your Destination property shouldn't be a list, it's just a string.  The drop down list for the DestinationTable would be the list.

Comment: @LarsTech But then how would the DestinationTable list get populated?

Answer (score 1):

The Mine class isn't holding a list of destinations, only a single destination, so your class should look like this:

```
public class Mine {
  public bool Transfer { get; set; }
  public string Source { get; set; }
  public string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

Then using a DataGridView control that has those three columns you specified, this is a quick example to get it running:

```
Column1.DataPropertyName = "Transfer";
Column2.DataPropertyName = "Source";
Column3.DataPropertyName = "Destination";
Column3.DataSource = new List<string>() { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" }; 

List<Mine> grid = new List<Mine>();
grid.Add(new Mine() { Transfer = true, Source = "xxx", Destination = "bbb" });
grid.Add(new Mine() { Transfer = false, Source = "yyy", Destination = "aaa" });
grid.Add(new Mine() { Transfer = true, Source = "zzz", Destination = "ccc" });

dataGridView1.DataSource = grid;
```

Column3 is the ComboBox column where you specify the list of options in the DataSource property of that column, so the list is separate from the class of Mine objects.